# Finding the average time (in seconds) for multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime

I'm currently trying to find an average between two different dates for multiple rows. So for each created date subtract the assigned date. Then find an average across all datediff (looking for a result in seconds)

```
declare @offset int; 
declare @st_date date;
declare @en_date date;

set @offset = (@BrowserTimezoneOffSet);
set @st_date = (@st_datein);
set @en_date = (@en_datein);

select 
 avg(subtract) as [AVG Assigned Time]
 from
    (select
        DATEDIFF(ss, ign.createdDate, ign.assignDate) as subtract
        from
        (select
            DATEADD(mi,@offset,s.CreatedDateTime) as createdDate
            ,DATEADD(mi,@offset,w.AuditHistoryDateTime) as assignDate
        from ServiceReq s, Audit_ServiceReq w
        WHERE   
        w.OwnerTeam_IsChanged = N'True' --owner was actually changed at some point
        AND s.Subject = N'General Request'
        AND w.AuditHistoryUser != N'InternalServices' --Doesn't include those done automagically by system
        AND w.AuditHistoryEventType != 1 --Doesn't include creation
        AND DATEADD(mi,@offset,s.CreatedDateTime) >= @st_date --greater than start date
        AND DATEADD(mi,@offset,s.CreatedDateTime) <= @en_date --less than end date
        AND s.CreatedByTeam in ('IT Helpdesk','Unassigned') --check the team
        ) as ign enter code here
    ) as dp
```

The above isn't returning accurate data I'm pretty new at this and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate `isn't returning accurate`? Can u give us some example data and result...

Comment: So offset = 600 (Australian time) and for anything between the start (01/02/2014) and end of February (28/02/2014). In seconds the query is returning 193272 seconds from almost 500 rows. However, I'm looking for something in 1000 ish as a return.

I believe this might be because the DATEDIFF is only looking at min and max from the rows rather then iteratively

Comment: Could you illustrate the problem with an example? It is not clear how the two tables you are retrieving data from are related to each other (as in "1:1, 1:N, N:N?"). A good and concise example of what the source datasets look like and what output should be returned for them might be enough to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

while you might be able to make this work, it's probably not the best way to approach it.

I'd either retrieve the rows and do the calculation in code (if it's guaranteed to be relatively small number of rows), or write a stored procedure that retrieves the rows with a cursor and iterates them to calculate what you want.

Either approach would be much more readable, and therefore much more maintainable than an extremely complex sql query.

I'd expect it to perform better, too. Over the years, I've consistently seen simple selects with cursor-based access for calculations outperform complex select statements.

Comment: I have no issues going down the stored procedure path. I guess my failing is my lack of SQL knowledge. How would the conversion code look like?

Comment: I agree that there are benefits to implementing logic in a stored procedure rather than in a client-side multi-statement batch, but from your wording (*‘…or write a stored procedure that retrieves the rows with a cursor…’*) it seems a little as if a stored procedure is *necessary* for one to use a cursor, which is not true for Transact-SQL. Or maybe I'm reading too much into it.

Comment: Yes, you're reading too much into it. The point is that ANSI SQL is   based on set operations, and this is more of a row-by-row type.of problem.